# What does this notation mean in a pushdown automaton?

Tags: compiler-construction, computation-theory, pushdown-automaton

My teacher uses weird formatting for PDA, can anybody explain this notation to me

The transition function is given as:

> [q,a,λ, s,B]
>
> [s,a,λ,s,λ]
>
> [s,b,B,s,λ]

```
Q={q,s} and inputs {a,b} stack {B}, final state F={s} M={Q, E, stack, transition function, q,F}
```

Can anybody explain this transition function notation?

Answer (score 0):

The transition function for PDAs is often a transition *relation* rather than a function. Each five-tuple (a, b, c, d, e) means "if in state a and reading symbol b with stack top c, pop c, go to state d, then push e."

Hope this helps!